# MVC 5 Delete Action in Details Page

Tags: model-view-controller, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

In this MVC5 project, I want my Details page to also serve as Edit page and Delete page.

I'm tackling this task by creating 2 forms, one with everything needed to update the data, including the submit button.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.EmpresaID)
    ...
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submeter" />
}
```

Now, for my second form, I basicly have a Delete button:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.EmpresaID)
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Delete" />
}
```

Error:

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of
>   non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method
>   'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult]
>   DeleteConfirmed(Int32)'

I tried to use a ActionLink, but then I get a HTTP 404. Which is odd, since I am being sent to the correct destination:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = Model.EmpresaID })
```

Sends to

```
.../Empresa/Delete/6
```

**EDIT1**

Action Method:

```
// POST: Empresa/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            Empresa empresa = await db.Empresas.FindAsync(id);
            db.Empresas.Remove(empresa);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

**EDIT2**

Action Method

```
// POST: Empresa/Delete/5
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Delete([Bind(Include = "EmpresaID,Nome,Estado,Severidade,Inicio,Fim")] Empresa empresa)
{
    //Do something with the posted viewModel
    Empresa e = await db.Empresas.FindAsync(empresa.EmpresaID);

    db.Empresas.Remove(e);

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Details.cshtml:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "Empresa", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.EmpresaID)
    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = Model.EmpresaID })
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Delete">Delete</button>
}
```

The ActionLink does not show any errors, but it doesn't delete anything either.

The Button gives me a HTTP 404. What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT3**

```
    // POST: Empresa/Delete/5
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Delete([Bind(Include = "EmpresaID,Nome,Estado,Severidade,Inicio,Fim")] Empresa empresa)
    {
        //Do something with the posted viewModel
        Empresa e = await db.Empresas.FindAsync(empresa.EmpresaID);

        db.Empresas.Remove(e);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

The only problem with EDIT2 was that I forgot to save the changes.

It's now working properly.

Comment: Please show the code for the Action method.

Comment: see updated question @buffjape

Comment: Is the 404 error before or after the form has posted? You also need to save the changes to the database like so `db.SaveChanges()` after the line `db.Empresas(e)`. Plus what is `e` in this context?

Comment: That was the problem Gareth, i forgot the command to save changes. e is the Empresa i'm deleting.

Answer (score 4):

You need to tell the form which action to complete along with the `FormMethod` i.e. `GET` or `POST`. So for your delete action for example, something like this:

```
@model MyProject.SomeViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "Empresa", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.EmpresaId)

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Delete">Delete</button>
}
```

And then in your controller something like:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Delete(SomeViewModel viewModel)
    {
        //Do something with the posted viewModel

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your input @Gareth, so I adapted my code, yet still can't delete.

Comment: It's working now, I needed to save the changes. await db.SaveChangesAsync();

Answer (score 0):

```
// EmpressasController

// POST: Empresas/Delete/5
[HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
{
    var empresa = _db.Empresas.Find(id);
    if (empresa != null) _db.Empresas.Remove(empresa);
    _db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}


// Razor View
@using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "Empresas", FormMethod.Post))
{
     @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
     @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.EmpresaId)

     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
}
```